# Data tables in R with for loops by lists of files with pattern matching

Tags: r, for-loop, pattern-matching

In a directory, I have 780 files and I need to bind them by rows, using R, in 78 different files and then write a .txt by file. The names of files are like these:

```
S1_S1_F1.xlsx 
S1_S2_F1.xlsx
...
S1_S5_F1.xlsx
S1_S6_F2.xlsx
...
S1_S10_F2.xlsx
S2_S1_F1.xlsx
```

The first part of the expresion `S1_(.*).xlsx` repeats 10 times, then changes up to `S78_(.*).xlsx`, with the second part changing from `(.*)_S1(.*).xlsx` to `(.*)S10(.*).xlsx`. I need to combine the files just by the second term to have 78 files from `S1.txt` to `S78.txt`.

I'm far from being an expert in R, so my approach was to do it file by file with the following code:

```
S1<-list.files(pattern = "^S1(.*).xlsx")
S1<-lapply(S1,read_excel)
S1 <- bind_rows(S1)
write.table(S1, "S1.txt", sep="\t",row.names=FALSE)
```

up to

```
S78<-list.files(pattern = "^S78(.*).xlsx")
S78 <-lapply(S78,read_excel)
S78 <- bind_rows(S78)
write.table(S78, "S1.txt", sep="\t",row.names=FALSE)
```

As you can see, this code seems to have been written by an australopithecus (which I'm not), so I beg your help! How can I do it with a for loop?

Comment: What does not work? Error? Undesired results?

Comment: @Parfait It works, but I just want to improve the code with a for loop to apply it to another directory with 10 times more files. Otherwise I'll do it all again the same way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply wrap another `lapply` (which is a loop) around your lines iterating through the sequence of 1 to 78. Below will output the 78 txt files and leave you a list of 78 dataframes:

```
dfList <- lapply(seq(1,78), function(i) {

  f <- list.files(pattern = paste0("^S", i, "(.*).xlsx"))
  dfs <- lapply(f, read_excel)     
  df <- bind_rows(dfs)           # OR base R'S do.call(rbind, dfs)
  write.table(df, paste0("S", i, ".txt"), sep="\t", row.names=FALSE)

  return(df)
})

dfList[[1]]
dfList[[2]]
...
dfList[[78]]
```

And even use `sapply` to return a named list:

```
dfList <- sapply(paste0("S",seq(1,78)), function(i) {

  f <- list.files(pattern = paste0("^", i, "(.*).xlsx"))
  dfs <- lapply(f, read_excel)
  df <- bind_rows(dfs)
  write.table(df, paste0(i, ".txt"), sep="\t", row.names=FALSE)

  return(df)
}, simplify = FALSE)

dfList$S1
dfList$S2
...
dfList$S78
```